# Unable to export a function from a custom node.js module

Tags: javascript, module.exports

I am testing out a simple *node.js* custom module represetned by the *processTest.js* file in the *node.js* root directory. Here is its contents: notice that the `module.export`s includes the one function `processTest()`:

```
'use strict';

const { spawn } = require( 'child_process' );
const ls = spawn( 'ls', [ '-lh', '/usr' ] );

function runTest() {
  ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
  });

  ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
  });

  ls.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
  });
}
module.exports = runTest;
```

In the main *node.js* script we try to invoke it as follows:

```
const processTest = require("./processTest")

...

http.createServer(app).listen(port, '0.0.0.0', function () {
  console.debug(`HTTP: Listening on ${port} ..`)
  processTest.runTest();
})
```

However we get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: processTest.runTest is not a function

note that the `processTest` module is actually present and the function is visible.

[image]
What is wrong here and how should it be corrected?

Comment: Try `processTest()` instead?

Comment: `processTest()` did not work - I needed to change the module exports as shown in the [soon to be] accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to the function in the `processTest` file. (`module.exports = runTest`). Use `require("./processTest")()`

Or just change the `module.exports` to

```js
module.exports = {
    runTest
}
```

and `require("./processTest").runTest()` will work

Comment: No reason to overwrite the export with a new object. It's much better to simply assign `module.exports.runTest = runTest;`